# redeclaration error in enum on same line

Tags: c, visual-c++, enums, mex, redeclaration

I am trying to create a Matlab interface to a device where the manufacturer has provided an SDK written in/for MS Visual C++. I included, in my C file (containing mexfunction) a header from the SDK that contains an enum as follows:

```
typedef enum {
 GROUP_SYSTEM_COMMAND = 0,
 GROUP_SLM_CURRENT,  // 1
 GROUP_SLM_HISTORY,  // 2
 GROUP_SLM_OVERALL,  // 3
 GROUP_STAT_HISTORY, // 4
 GROUP_STAT_OVERALL, // 5
 GROUP_OBA11,        // 6
 GROUP_OBA13,        // 7
 GROUP_DOSE_1,       // 8
 GROUP_DOSE_2,       // 9
 GROUP_EVENT_1,      // 10
 .......etc
```

When compiling the C file in matlab to generate the mex file, I get several errors for each one of the elements of the enum as follows:

Error \LxT\useLxt.c: \LxT\LxT831.h: 713  redeclaration of `GROUP_DOSE_1' previously    declared at \LxT\LxT831.h 713

Error \LxT\useLxt.c: \LxT\LxT831.h: 714  redeclaration of `GROUP_DOSE_2' previously declared at \LxT\LxT831.h 714 
....

The confusing part is that the redeclaration is on the same line. Also another thing to note is that this is cpp code while matlab is using the lcc c compiler. Any hints/suggestions?

Comment: Does your header file have header guards?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the same names have not been used elsewhere in the code

Comment: Header guards are present yes

Comment: Make sure your header guards are correctly implemented. It provides the best explanation for your problem.

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a minimal testcase and post the minimal testcase here. You should be able to get it down to less than 50 lines by removing anything that's unnecessary to reproduce the problem.